# How to index a csv document in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm trying to upload some csv files in elastic search. I don't want to mess it up , so I'm writing for some guidance. Can someone help with a video/tutorial/documentation , of how to index a document in elastic search?  I've read the official documentation, but I feel a bit lost as a begginer. It will be fine If you'll recommend me a video tutorial , or you'll describe me some steps. Hope you are all doing well! Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use Logstash, which is official and very fast pipeline for elastic ,you can download it from [here](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/logstash)

First of all create a configuration file as below example and save it as logstashExample.conf in bin directory of logstash.
With assuming that elastic server and kibana console are up and running , run the configuration file with this command "./logstash -f logstashExample.conf" .

I've also added a suitable example of related configuration file for Logstash , please change the index name in output and your file path in input with respect of your need, you can also disable filtering by removing csv components in below example.

```html
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/timo/bitcoin-data/*.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
   sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","
#Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume (BTC),Volume (Currency),Weighted Price
     columns => ["Date","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume (BTC)", "Volume (Currency)" ,"Weighted Price"]
  }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
     hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
     index => "bitcoin-prices"
  }
stdout {}
}
```